# New to SQL and am having trouble with Select queries

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: `Book`, `Customer` and `Trans`. I am trying to write a select query that reports the `Name` and `Book` Title of anyone who purchased a book in September. The tables have been successfully created, and all the data is in them, but I can't get this select query to work. I have tried everything. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Name, b.Title, t.TDate
FROM Customer as c, Book as b, Trans as t;
WHERE c.ID=t.ID AND b.BookID=t.BookID and t.TDate < '2003-10-01';
```

I'm trying to avoid duplicates as well.

Comment: We can't help you without the schema of the tables. (Do `desc Book` ...)

Comment: That semicolon after `Trans as t;` is faulty. Remove that.

Comment: Relabeling your tables as c b and t isn't really needed, if you're just starting it might help to write it out without them.  Select distinct customer.name, book.title, trans.tdate from customer, book, trans where customer.id = trans.id and book.bookid = trans.bookid and trans.tdate < '2003-10-01';- do you have records where the customer.id and the trans.id match?  Returning no matches and not an error is a sign the join isnt returning results.  Also eventually youll want to start specifying joins in tables but I think it's easier to grasp conceptually the way you're doing it now.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.Name, b.Title
FROM Customer as c
JOIN Trans as t ON c.ID = t.ID
JOIN Book as b ON b.BookID = t.BookID
WHERE t.TDate >= '2003-10-01' and t.TDate < '2003-11-01'
GROUP BY c.Name, b.Title
```

Comment: problem with the WHERE... WHERE MONTH(t.TDate) = 10 AND YEAR(t.TDate) = 2003

Comment: you say its less than september but the OP wants it in that month

Comment: @JohnRuddell: Thanks, I missed that. I used a version that can make use of indexes.

Comment: all good :) your version is better than mine... i was just sayin where the month and year are equal to the date lol

Comment: so im fairly new to stackoverflow... what good does +1 ing a comment do? i +1'd your answer btw :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell: Upvoted comments won't be hidden if a post contains more comments than being displayed. That keeps the important comments visible. (You have to click on *show more comments* to see all if a post has many) Besides that it is an indicator of a good comment.

Comment: Can you please explain what the difference is between joining the tables like you have shown, and like how I have shown? I got yours to work (so thank you greatly!) but I'm still a little confused how they can't be joined in the WHERE clause by stating "c.ID = t.ID and b.BookID=t.BookID" I just ask because that's how we have been taught to join in my database class. Granted we just started working on it yesterday, but still :D

Comment: @user3420788 You can't `SELECT` from multiple tables without some sort of `JOIN` or `UNION`.

Comment: But I thought that's what I had done by stating "FROM Customer as c, Book as b, and Trans as t"?

Comment: @user3420788: Yes, you joined. But that is legacy super old syntax. Better use the explicit join syntax. There you can differ between the join conditions (in the `ON` clause) and filtering your records in the `where` clause. And if you need a specific join and not the default one, then you have to use the new syntax anyway.